# repopulating $_POST variables transparently in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, forms, browser

So. 
In a LAMP stack (PHP), I've got this situation where I'm showing an intermediate page based on some variable from the first page --more simply, I have one page called, say, ListOfProjects, from which I can select a project to view.

When I go to that project, there are other page-navigation elements (like looking at individual jobs in the project, say) the user can click. Once I click them, and am navigated away from the intermediate page between ListOfProjects and IndividualJob, I have to resubmit the data that got me there.

That's fine, and if I could do it automatically, I would. However, I haven't found a way to force this behavior and eliminate the extra click and the ugly "Confirm Form Resubmission" screen.

Does anyone know a way I could A) silently force form-resubmission when the user hits the back button or B) avoid the situation where there's a form that needs resubmitting?

I've thought about trying to just pass that project ID to the session variable, but it's well within scope to have more than one individual project open in the same browser, which would make that unwieldy.

Thoughts? Suggestions? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use POST.

When you are getting data from the server, use GET and put the data in the query string.

POST is designed for sending data to the server that will make a change (e.g. updating data in the database), it isn't appropriate for just deciding what data to look at.

Comment: And this will work without the messy intermediate step after using the back button?

Comment: Yes. GET requests aren't supposed to signal a server to change anything, so browsers don't ask you if you are sure if you try to repeat one.

Comment: Beautiful. What a simple, overlooked fix. Thanks, @Quentin.

Answer (score -1):

Some solution is bypass using jQuery to resubmit a form when click on back:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['ListOfProject'])): ?>
    <form method="POST" id="backToProject"></form>
    <script>$("#backToProject").submit()</script>
<?php endif ?>
```

Another solution is to use `header("Location: ...")` to force users to redirect a page, BUT you should remove all previous $_POST request using `unset($_POST)` such as:

```
unset($_POST);
header("Location: your_uri://your_path");
```

Try reload a page and reload a page using javascript into `<script>` tag such as:

```
if ($_POST['ListOfProject'])
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">location.reload();</script>';
}
```

Try to understand GET/POST method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

And I don't recommended using link of sites using $_POST method such as say Quentin user.